# How to update pagination list when delete JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is there any easy option to  update pagination and `filteredTodos` when delete items from `todos`
Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpveqL

```css
var todos = angular.module('todos', ['ui.bootstrap']);
todos.controller('TodoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.filteredTodos = [];
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.numPerPage = 10;
  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.makeTodos = function() {
  $scope.todos = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= 66; i++) {
      $scope.todos.push({id: i, text: 'todo ' + i, done: false});
    }
  };
  $scope.makeTodos();
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage),
      end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
  });
  $scope.deleteMe = function (id) {
    $scope.todos.splice(0, 1);
  };
});
```

```html
<pagination 
 ng-model="currentPage"
 total-items="todos.length" 
 max-size="maxSize" 
 boundary-links="true" 
 previous-text="&lsaquo;" 
 next-text="&rsaquo;" 
 first-text="&laquo;" 
 last-text="&raquo;"
></pagination>
```

Comment: Use a filter instead of a different array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172426/connecting-angular-bootstrap-ui-paginate-to-table/31182565#31182565

Comment: Updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jme11/pen/mJXjyZ?editors=101).  The reason this works is that the filter is non-destructive.  Filters return a new array that is used by the repeat (or piped to the next filter).  ngRepeat automatically watches the scoped array that it is bound to so you don't need the extra watch.  More details about creating a custom filter is in the other question I linked (which I literally answered earlier today).