# Angular-bootstrap pagination - not getting variable in 'scope'

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<table ng-show="ecu.dtcs">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <uib-accordion close-others="true">
                    <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="dtc in dtcList track by $index">
                        ...
                    </uib-accordion-group>
                </uib-accordion>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<uib-pagination
    total-items="{{ totalItems }}"
    ng-model="{{ currentPage }}"
    items-per-page="{{ itemsPerPage }}"
    boundary-link-numbers="true"
    ng-change="setPagingData(currentPage)">
</uib-pagination>
```

**JS** *(directive)*

```
link: function (scope) {

    scope.showEcuDetails = function (ecu) {

        // For pagination
        scope.itemsPerPage = 20;
        scope.totalItems = ecu.dtcs.length;
        scope.currentPage = 1;

        scope.setPagingData = function(currentPage) {
            var start = (currentPage - 1) * scope.itemsPerPage,
                end = currentPage * scope.itemsPerPage;

            scope.dtcList = ecu.dtcs.slice(start, end);
        };

        scope.setPagingData(scope.currentPage);
    };
}
```

- `ecu.dtcs`: Holds all the data that I want
- `dtcList`: Holds the `sliced` list each 20 elements

I have used the [Angular-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) documentation and have also referenced this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702042/how-to-use-ui-bootstrap-pagination-for-a-table-generated-using-ng-repeat/37704512#37704512) (except have used `ng-change` to alter the list instead of a `$watch` on the scope)

I have debugged the application thoroughly and I can see that `dtcList` is becoming populated wiht the first 20 elements. However, going into the HTML, there is nothing displayed

I have also tried to write a `.filter` (like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172426/connecting-angular-bootstrap-ui-paginate-to-table#31182565)) but because the variables are being set in the scope of the directive and not a controller, my filter, cannot see the variables

**N.B:** For the pagination settings, to reference the scope variables (i.e. `totalItems`), I have used Angular expressions like displayed in this question and also basic strings as in the documentation (i.e. `"totalItems"`)

I think the concepts and the way I have it written at the moment should work, it's just the HTML cannot see `dtcList` for some reason

**EDIT**

It may help to know that this is in an angular-ui-bootstrap modal. Below the function call to `setPagingData()`, I have this:

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "ecuDialog.html",
    size: "lg",
    windowClass: "modalDialogs networkTest__largeContentDialog",
    scope: scope
});
```

The `templateUrl` is that of which I've written in the ***HTML*** section of this question. It crossed my mind whether this was the issue but my colleagues have assured me that it would not impact the result in any way.

**EDIT 2**

Unfortunately, 1 of our colleagues who specialises in AngularJS has viewed the code along with the documentation and cannot see any errors within it. Could it be an Angular bug or is it the combination of multiple elements from `angular-ui-bootstrap` that it doesn't like?

Things I am combining are:

- `ui-modal`
- `ui-accordion`
- `ui-pagination`

Comment: CAn you please provide us with a fillde?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as the app is too dense and pulls data/elements from many other places and they are too heavy to mock. I will update my question to provide more details though

Comment: That would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution:*

My code was correct. My colleague had an attempts at it and just took the code I had written into another directive. We were both unsure why this was the case, maybe Angular doesn't like overcrowded directives?